# Unable to get Refresh Token in Google Calendar Version 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api

I am developing my for Google Integration in ASP.NET. I am tring to create a service using access token and refresh token. But i am unable to get the refresh token as i am just getting Access Token, Token Type and Expires in. Please check the below code for this.

```
 private String ExchangeCodeWithAccessAndRefreshToken()
{
    string Url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    string grant_type = "authorization_code";
    string redirect_uri_encode = UrlEncodeForGoogle(Convert.ToString(Session["URL"]));
    string data = "code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}&grant_type={4}";
    string Code = Request.QueryString["Code"];
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
    string result = null;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    String ClientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientID"].ToString();
    String ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"].ToString();
    string param = string.Format(data, Code, ClientID, ClientSecret, redirect_uri_encode, grant_type);
    var bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param);
    using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
    }

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }
    var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var tokenData = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<GoogleTokenModel>(result);
    return tokenData.Access_Token;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [access_type=offline](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline) in your URL:

```
string data = "code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}&grant_type={4}&access_type=offline";
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but i resolved that problem by specifying access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force and previously i was using access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto

Comment: I want to know one more thing, as i am migrating from version 2 to version 3 so i am unable to do any operation by using the refresh token of version 2 so is there any other alternative for this so that i can use my already existing refresh token.

Comment: that should really be a new question as it's a different topic.